What is the reasoning behind this boilerplate start-up code?
Here's a snippet from disassembled output of a simple program with gcc on Linux:
  400478:   ff 15 6a 0b 20 00       callq  *0x200b6a(%rip)        # 600fe8 <__libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5>
  40047e:   f4                      hlt  


Why is hlt needed here?

From my understanding, it is if the program fails to exit and it would then trap. However, in what situations would the program fail to exit like this?


Where is the definition for __libc_start_main?

My understanding is it may be dynamically linked.



I'm compiling code to assembly myself and am in particular curious on how to handle program start-up.

As you say the hlt is just a safety net. The comment in the code says "Crash if somehow 'exit' does return."  Yes, __libc_start_main is typically dynamically linked.

Does this mean that exit may return? @Jester To me, that strikes me as unbelievable. I'm not sure if I should emit similar safety net code, since if exit returns, what even is to say hlt works?

Come off it. HLT is a machine instruction. It works. Somebody could hook or replace exit(). They can't frig around with HLT.

I do mean the syscall @user207421 , which then would tell you you're running under a malicious (or otherwise broken) OS. It just seems improbable to program for, and I'm trying to understand the reasoning.

No, you don't mean the syscall. HLT is a machine instruction. Not a system call. That's why it appears in the instruction field, just like CALLQ, not the label field, like __libc_start_main. It may seem 'improbable to code for', but it if happens the compiler has to halt execution somehow, otherwise it will continue into whatever comes next. As a matter of fact it won't halt the processor, it will cause a privilege trap.

I mean the syscall for exit @user207421

exit() is not a system call either, it is a C library function which wraps a system call. The actual system call is system-dependent.

I am referring to the relevant system call for exit @user207421 I don't know how to be more clear than I already am. The question is : when would that fail and why is the hlt needed? And what makes the privilege trap do anything, if the underlying exit syscall already failed, since you're just going back to the OS?

Sigh. __libc_start_main calls exit(). Both are in the C library. Both are at least theoretically replaceable. And in any case there is still a theoretical risk that the system call will return as well, which has to be covered. It's only one instruction. Nothing to worry about really.

Either way, my question is simply as I said. Why would we need a backup for when the syscall relevant to exit fails? That is the situation I am dealing with, not with a C library wrapper.

I've answered that.

The theoretical risk, as mentioned, is not clear. I've explained, twice. If it fails, it means the OS failed. What makes you think hlt is any better, since it goes to the OS?

You miss the point which is that the syscall might not even be invoked. It does not fail.

I don't really understand that point @Jester . The other user was talking of a case where it is invoked but fails.

This isn't much of a safety net anyway, we're just one stack smash away from not returning to that hlt in the first place.

The "hlt" was probably put there by someone who, unlike some other clang/gcc maintainers, recognizes a distinction between "sitautions where something happens that shouldn't" and "sitautions where nothing a program might do would be unacceptable", and views a byte for a 'hlt' instruction as a reasonable cost to make such a distinction.

Which way is the distinction swinging @supercat ? "situations where nothing a program might do would be unacceptable" -- seems to imply UB, which I presume this is trying to avoid.

@user129393192: Not all compiler writers buy into the notion that the Standard's waiver of jurisdiction over a corner case--which is what "Undefined Behavior" indicates, represents a judgment by the Committee that programmers won't care about what happens.

@user129393192: Sometimes a misconfigured signal handler may cause a signal to return even when it shouldn't, and many compiler writers would regard the execution of arbitrary code if that happens to be undesirable, regardless of whether the Standard would forbid it.

What puzzles me is how you are so certain that __libc_start_main  calls the system call directly rather than calling exit(). I wonder how you can know that.

The source code for this startup code is in the glibc source at sysdeps/x86_64/start.S line 117 and includes a comment saying what you already surmised:
    hlt         /* Crash if somehow `exit' does return.  */

Note that __libc_start_main, whose source is at csu/libc-start.c line 209, ends with a call to __libc_start_call_main, which ends with a call to exit.
So the only way that the hlt would be reached is if one of those functions returned for some reason, which they are not supposed to do.  (And they are declared with __attribute__((noreturn)) so that the compiler should also warn if, when compiling those functions, it detects that they could return.)  Thus this is presumably just the glibc programmer exercising an (over)abundance of caution, just in case the glibc programmers who wrote those other functions had messed up somehow and written a return statement where they should not.  I don't think there was any real expectation that it would actually happen.
As you suggest in the comments, we can imagine more exotic scenarios where this could be reached, e.g. the exit system call returning.  That would only happen if the kernel were badly broken, and of course we could imagine that it is so badly broken that executing a privileged instruction such as hlt, which normally kills the process with a SIGSEGV, would fail to do so.  But I can't think of any halfway realistic way for that to actually happen.  In any case, I don't think it is the scenario that the hlt is trying to protect against.
I also don't think it's meant to protect against error by the application programmer who might have hooked exit or something like that, or against an exploit that might be redirecting program flow.  As mentioned in comments, there are so many bad things that could happen in those scenarios, that trying to protect any one of them would be a waste of time.


I'm compiling code to assembly myself and am in particular curious on how to handle program start-up.

Rather than trying to dig through the glibc source code, you may find it more expedient to start with the System V ABI.  Section 3.4 tells you about the state of the registers and stack that you can expect at your program's entry point (traditionally called _start), whose address will be in the ELF header as specified by the -e flag to the linker ld.  When your program is done, you invoke the _exit system call via the usual syscall instruction interface.  If you wish to insert a trapping instruction after that, go right ahead, but it isn't at all necessary.
